# Python 3 - Django 1.9 One Create Request Causing Multiple Creation Attempts?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I was adding a successful or unsuccessful message to when a post is created on a learn to make a blog project when I started getting that post creations were both successful and unsuccessful at the same time:

### [image: Current Result]

The contents of the message are defined using if/else statements and the only thing I can think might be happening is when I click submit on my post creation form it is being submitted multiple times causing an initial successful attempt and then two unsuccessful attempts but I don't see a reason for this to be happening in views.py, post_form.html, or post_detail.html files. Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this?

**views.py**:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post

def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Not Successfully Created")
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```

**post_form.html**:

```
<!--DOCTYPE html -->

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>

<form method="POST", action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" name="Create Post"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**post_detail.html**:

```
<!--DOCTYPE html -->

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{     message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

<body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

{{ instance.title }}<br/>
{{ instance.content }}<br/>
{{ instance.timestamp }}<br/>
{{ instance.updated }}<br/>
{{ instance.id }}<br/>
<br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this always happen (i.e. you get 3x messages each time you use the form)? The messages framework will display any messages that have been queued when rendering in a template. This means if you call `messages.success()` a few times, but don't visit a page that shows the messages, they will be queued until a time you do visit a page outputting them and then they'll all be shown at once.

Comment: Frequently it is 3 messages but sometimes it's 2 or 4 messages always with 1 successful message last. A view of the created post and a view of the post creation page using a form might be creating the unsuccessful messages then creating a post is successful and I just don't understand that its normal for the code to going down the else path in those circumstances. That would follow your insight that all stored messages are being displayed.

Comment: I'd suggest adding some `print()` statements to your view then and watching the console to see what's going on. Can't see that you're doing anything silly above, so there's no reason it should be going through the view multiple times.

Comment: Actually, are you sure you're not entering invalid form data a few times and triggering `messages.error(request, "Not Successfully Created")`? As this doesn't show up on your form page, you'll continue adding these up until you eventually submit a valid form (very unlikely what you intended).

Comment: I repeated getting the successful and unsuccessful messages to be displayed and the server only sees one POST so if I really want both successful and unsuccessful messages to be implemented I will just need to alter the code to display only the last message instead of iterating over all messages stored `{% for message in messages %}` since it seems to be gathering unintentional unsuccessful messages.